# How to integrate with Facebook and Google Plus accounts?

Tags: service

I am not understanding how to integrate with **Facebook** and **Google Plus** accounts to retrieve the user data and Utilize that data for registering my customer service portal. This requirement is similar to the functionality we will see in the Mobile Application like Flipkart, Amazon.
Please guide me on this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. [tour] [ask]

Comment: You should refer [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) and [G+](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) Login API documentation.